# nc command: conflict between different Ubuntu machines

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, command-line, virtualbox, netcat

I am using Ubuntu 14.04. Then I have an Ubuntu 12.04 machine running on virtualbox. On the virtual box machine I listened on port 12345 using the command

```
nc -l 12345
```

And on the host machine, I entered

```
echo "Test" | nc targetIP 12345
```

But nothing has been displayed on the listening terminal.
I have checked the reverse. i.e., listened on the host machine and entered the echo command on the guest machine. It works well.

What could be the reason? nc specific or virtualbox specific?

Comment: There are two different ports in your question.

Comment: @A.B. Ah... My bad. I have edited. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: may be something to do with the way you setup the networking (host-only, NAT, etc) in the virtual machine.

Comment: But I am able to communicate successfully in the reverse direction. If I listen on host machine then I am able to nc from my guest machine and texts can be sent in both directions. In that case I dont think its network dependent.

Comment: After opening port 12345 on vbox, do `echo "Test" | nc localhost 12345` from another terminal of vbox..whats the result ?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and confirm that you can actually access the guest machine with that IP. Can you, for example, `ssh targetIP`? Or `ping targetIP`? Then, also add your networking setup. Are they on the same subnet? We need to know the details of how you've set up the networking on both machines in order to be able to help.

Comment: It's impossible to answer your question with so little information. Give us more data about your network configuration.